# Copying Excel range to Outlook results in String value True

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Trying to copy an Excel range to Outlook mail body.

No errors, but when the macro is run I get

> Please order from the inserted excel.
> True

I can copy and paste manually and get a somewhat table looking structure with some color, easily visible and legible.

I'm trying to accomplish this with `.PasteSpecial`.

I tried using For loops, but then it is not formatted and impossible to read, without a lot of work.

```vb
Sub Send_Email()
'sends full order to joey@

    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xAddress As String
    Dim xMailOut As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim xOutApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim orderTime As String
    Dim orderDate As String
    Dim orderTimeDateFinal As String
    Dim xEmailBody As String
    
    orderDate = Format(Date, "MM-DD-YY")
    orderTime = Format(Time, "hh-nn AM/PM")
    
    orderTimeDateFinal = orderTime & " : " & orderDate
    
    On Error Resume Next
    xAddress = ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Address
    Set xRg = Range("A4:V50")
    
    xRg.Copy
    
    MsgBox xRg
    If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xMailOut = xOutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
   
    xEmailBody = "Please order from the inserted excel." & vbNewLine & xRg.PasteSpecial
    With xMailOut
        .Subject = "CEM Tooling Order " & orderTimeDateFinal
        .Importance = olImportanceHigh
        .To = "joey@cuttingedgemanuf.com"
        .Body = xEmailBody
        .Display
        'remove comment on line below to auto send the emails.
        '.Send
    End With
    Set xMailOut = Nothing
    Set xOutApp = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you clarify what the issue is? Are you trying to copy the entire `xRg` values to the email? Why PasteSpecial, to keep formatting?  One issue is AFAIK you can't run a command (e.g. `PasteSpecial`) while setting a variable. That `xRg.PasteSpecial` needs to be a `String`.

Comment: I would look into using email-body as HTML element. xMailOut.Body => xMailOut.HTMLBody. This would at least keep the HTML formatting

Comment: @BruceWayne yes entire value should be copied. paste special because paste doesnt appear to be an option in the pop up. not sure where you mean im running a command while setting a variable.

Comment: @HavardKleven any documentation on this? not sure where to start, id consider doing it that route if i have docs to look over to help me on my way.

Comment: Sorry, don’t got much documentation at the moment. However, a quick google-search for “VBA Mailitem HTML” might point you to the solution. Though, the change I mentioned in the previous comment might be enough for this particular issue

Comment: The command `xRg.PasteSpecial` will paste using `xRg` as the destination, and will return `True` when it has done this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're doing a `.PasteSpecial` while setting a variable:

```
xEmailBody = "Please order from the inserted excel." & vbNewLine & xRg.PasteSpecial
```

What you want to do instead, is create a string that is all of you `xRg` values. (I think? Do you really want to send 1034 cells' data (`A4:V50`) to the email?)

Try something like this:

```
xAddress = ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Address
Set xRg = Range("A4:V50")
If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Dim xRgValues as String
For Each cell In xRg.Cells
    ' This goes by column, then row. So A4, then B4, ..., V4, A5, B5, ...
    If cell.Address = xRg.Cells(1, 1).Address Then
        xRgValues = cell.Value
    Else
       ' Change the comma as needed for the separator.
        xRgValues = xRgValues & ", " & cell.Value
    End If
Next cell
.... 
xEmailBody = "Please order from the inserted excel." & vbNewLine & xRgValues
```

Edit: I wrote this Answer before clarifying, so it may or may not apply. This takes simply the values, no formatting, and puts that in the email. But perhaps the general loop idea is helpful.

Comment: yes. i already tried the loop method, but it makes it pretty hard to read.. if i can remove some of the columns out of the range it would be ok this way. but im not sure how to do that quite yet. realistically i only need to add columns A and V. i dont necessarily need the rest of it at all for what im trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the word editor but I think it needs to be displayed to work.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Send_Email()

    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xMailOut As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim xOutApp As Outlook.Application
    
    Set xRg = Range("A4:V50")
    xRg.Copy

    Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xMailOut = xOutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
   
    ' word objects
    Dim OutInsp, oWrdDoc, sText As String
    sText = "Please order from the inserted excel." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    With xMailOut
        .Display
        Set OutInsp = .GetInspector
        Set oWrdDoc = OutInsp.WordEditor
        With oWrdDoc
           .Paragraphs.Add.Range.Text = sText
           .Paragraphs.Add.Range.Paste
        End With
     
        .To = ""
        .Subject = "CEM Tooling Order " & Format(Now, "MM-DD-YY hh-nn AM/PM")
        .Importance = olImportanceHigh
           
    End With

    Set xMailOut = Nothing
    Set xOutApp = Nothing
   
End Sub
```